# what is the proper place to check for user attributes in a mean.js application?

Tags: mean-stack, meanjs

I have an app, based on mean.js boiler plate

in this app I need to check whether the current logged in user has an admin role:

```
var isAdmin = user.roles.indexOf('admin');
        if(isAdmin > 0){
            $rootScope.isAdmin = true;
        }
        else {
            $rootScope.isAdmin = false;
        }
```

What is the most proper place to do this?

Answer (score 0):

figured this out: first we make sure to have 'Authentication' included in out controller: `...'Authentication',...`  Then, we get our user: `var user = Authentication.user;`  Then, we define this function:

```
function assertIsAdmin(){
            var isAdmin = user.roles.indexOf('admin');
            if(isAdmin > 0){
                $scope.isAdmin = true;
            }
            else {
                $scope.isAdmin = false;
            }
        }
```

And then we call it:  assertIsAdmin();